# Change the value of a selected element depending on a input

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
const salary = document.querySelector('#salary').value;
const brand = document.querySelector('#brands');


function firstDigit(salary) {
    // 1: get first digit using regex pattern
    const matches = String(salary).match(/\d/);
    // 2: convert matched item to integer
    const digit = Number(matches[0]);
    // 3: add sign back as needed
    return (num < 0) ? -digit : digit;
}

let firstNumSalary = firstDigit();

salary.addEventListener("change", changeBrandValue);
function changeBrandValue() {
    if (firstNumSalary == 1) {
        brand.value = 'ford';    
    } else if (firstNumSalary == 6) {
        brand.value = 'mercedes';
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="brands">Choose a brand:</label>
<select name="brands" id="brands">
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<label for="salary">Your salary:</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">
```

I would like to change the selected value depending on the first digit of the input. For example if a user inputs a number that its first digit is 6 then the selected option will be Mercedes.

I tried the above code but it does not seem to work.

Comment: The code shown is producing an error on the console, have you noticed and investigated that?  It would appear you're trying to parse the value entered by the user before the user has been allowed to enter a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues which needed to be fixed in your code:

1. `const salary` should only be the element selection - you can extract the value dynamically when called.
2. the declaration of `firstNumSalary` should be within the event listener - this way it updates whenever the change occurs.
3. You do not need to pass in `salary` as a parameter for the firstDigit.

```js
const salary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brands');


function firstDigit() {
    // 1: get first digit using regex pattern
    const matches  = String(salary.value).match(/\d/);
    // 2: convert matched item to integer
    const digit = Number(matches[0]);
    // 3: add sign back as needed
    return (digit < 0) ? -digit : digit;
}



salary.addEventListener("change", changeBrandValue);
function changeBrandValue() {
    let firstNumSalary = firstDigit();

    if (firstNumSalary == 1) {
        brand.value = 'ford';    
    } else if (firstNumSalary == 6) {
        brand.value = 'mercedes';
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="brands">Choose a brand:</label>
<select name="brands" id="brands">
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<label for="salary">Your salary:</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Though, the code is not working as intended. For example when in the salary input field I type a salary of 65000, the selected value should be mercedes, but the select field remains unchanged.

Did you try it and it worked out for you?

Comment: So it works when you click out of the input box once you have typed a new value. This is because of how the `change` event listener works, i.e. it gets triggered when you click out of the input box. If you would like it to update as you are typing then I recommend using the `input` event listener - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event#examples

Comment: No, it does not work even when the input field loses focus. I checked my code many times, regarding your corrections, and really I don't know what I am doing wrong. It should work but apparently it does not.

Comment: Well your code might be different than the snippet above. Does the snippet above work for you if you click on the "Run code snippet" below my answer snippet and see? Also are you getting any errors?

Comment: I run the code snippet and it works fine!
When I run my code in the console I get an error:
"Uncaught TypeError: salary is null"

So I added this in the code:

if (salary !== undefined && salary !== null) {
    salary.addEventListener("change", changeBrandValue);
}

Now I don't get any error but still it does not work. Do you maybe have any idea why?

Comment: I found it out what was wrong. Thank you again for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues with your code.

1. The place you set `firstNumSalary` is not correct. It will evaluated at the first time only and after changing the value it won't get re evaluate. You need to move it inside `changeBrandValue()` function. Also pass salary value in function like `firstDigit(salary.value);`.
2. Use `const salary = document.querySelector('#salary');` instead of `const salary = document.querySelector('#salary').value;`
3. Correct return statement in `firstDigit` it should be like `return (digit < 0) ? -digit : digit;`

Try like below

```js
const salary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brands');

function firstDigit(salary) {
  // 1: get first digit using regex pattern
  const matches = String(salary).match(/\d/);
  // 2: convert matched item to integer
  const digit = Number(matches[0]);
  // 3: add sign back as needed
  return (digit < 0) ? -digit : digit;
}


salary.addEventListener("change", changeBrandValue);

function changeBrandValue() {

  let firstNumSalary = firstDigit(salary.value);

  if (firstNumSalary == 1) {
    brand.value = 'ford';
  } else if (firstNumSalary == 6) {
    brand.value = 'mercedes';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="brands">Choose a brand:</label>
<select name="brands" id="brands">
  <option value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<label for="salary">Your salary:</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const salary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brands');


function firstDigit(salary) {
    // 1: get first digit using regex pattern
    const matches = salary.match(/\d/);
    // 2: convert matched item to integer
    const digit = Number(matches[0]);
    // 3: add sign back as needed
    return (digit < 0) ? -digit : digit;
}


salary.addEventListener("change", changeBrandValue);
function changeBrandValue(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    if (!target.value) {
       return;
    }
    let firstNumSalary = firstDigit(target.value);
    if (firstNumSalary == 1) {
        brand.value = 'ford';    
    } else if (firstNumSalary == 6) {
        brand.value = 'mercedes';
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="brands">Choose a brand:</label>
<select name="brands" id="brands">
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>

<label for="salary">Your salary:</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">
```

Comment: What was the original problem?  What did you change?  How does that correct the problem?  Please include information about the answer when posting, rather than just giving someone code to copy/paste.